# Knockout.js Computed observable not binding to observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to get computed value and push these values to the observable array. Web Api controller returning simple values - just pure numbers without json wrap. May be this is issue. Please advise as I'm newbie to Knockout.
P.S. Here is two ajax call because they are calling different api's controllers.

```
 function GrafikViewModel(grafikUri) {
            var self = this;
            self.books = ko.observableArray();
            self.PaxLeft = ko.computed(function () {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.books(), function (book) {
                    $.getJSON("/api/orders/getpax/" + book.kodg, function (item) {
                        self.books().push(item);
                    });
                }, GrafikViewModel)
            });
            $.getJSON(grafikUri, function (data) {
                self.books(data.$values);
            });
        }
```

Comment: You want a computed with a side-effect? Are you sure? BTW you've created a circular dependency here - a computed that changes `books` and reacts to changes on `books`. I think you're on the wrong track, please explain what you actually are trying to do.

Comment: What you mean by side-effect? About circular dependency you're right. Should I change it to be self.PaxLeft (this is ko.observable)? Actually my goal is get data from two different controllers and put them togeyther into same observableArray.

Comment: I'm thinking about first ajax call. Could it be the problem that controller return just pure integer value, whithout any json wrap?

Comment: A computed is supposed to calculate a value that depends on other values in your view model. That's its effect. It is not supposed to *change* values on your view model (let alone its own base value). That would be a side-effect. You simply want your secondary Ajax calls after your primary one, I assume. Look into jQuery's `.then()` for chaining Ajax calls and get rid of the computed here.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to bind few ViewModels to the same element?

Comment: Templates or MasterViewModel?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your requirements are not clear to me. What does *"to bind few ViewModels to the same element"* mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do a little guess work, but I believe what you want is

```
self.books.push(item);
```

instead of

```
self.books().push(item);
```

Note the missing `()` there. The knockout observable array "mirrors" most of the array's functions. By using those instead of the ones provided by `Array`, knockout can keep track of changes happening to the wrapped array.

EDIT: You can find a list of all the "mirrored" functions at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray, about two pages down (section "Manipulating an observableArray")

Comment: I did changed, but this didn't helped.